# Developing a plugin based architecture on top of Spring

Tags: java, spring, plugins, architecture, servlet-filters

I've been scratching my head around developing a simple plugin based architecture on top of Spring, for one of my current apps. No matter how much separation one could achieve using patterns like MVC, one always reaches a point where coupling is inevitable.

Thus, I started weighing options. At first I thought that filters are a good one. Every plugin  I'd make would be a filter, which then I will simply insert into the filter map. Of course, this will create a bit of overhead when enumerating and checking all the filters, but at least , controllers won't have to care what has happened to the data before it reached them, or what happens afterwards, they will just care to fetch the models (through DAO or whatnot) and return them.

The problem with this is that not all of my app requests are HTTP-based. Some are based on emails, others are internally scheduled (timed), so Filters won't help much, unless I try to adapt every type of incoming request to HTTPRequest, which would be too much.

Another one I thought about was annotation based AOP, where I annotate every method, where the plugin would intercept methods based on certain conventions. My problem with is that first I am not so experienced with AOP in general, and second, simply writing all those conventions already suggests a bit of coupling

By far the option that mostly appeals to my way of thinking is using Spring-based events. Every type of request handler within my app (web controller, email handler, etc) will be a sort of an event dispatcher, which will dispatch Spring events on every major action. On the other hand, plugins will simply listen for when a particular event happens, and do some logic. This will allow me to utilize point #1 as well, as some of those plugins could be filters as well, i.e when they receive a notification that a certain controller action is done, they may just decide to do nothing, and rather wait for when they get called by the filter chain. I see this as a somewhat nice approach. Of course here comes the overhead again, of dispatching events, plus the fact that every involved class will eb coupled with Spring forever, but I see this as a necessary evil.

My main concern regarding Spring events is performance, both in terms of latency, and memory footprint.

I am still not an expert, so a bunch of feedback here would be of tremendous help. Are spring   events the best for this type of architecture, or there is another solution that I've missed? I am aware that there might even be some third-party solutions out there already, so  I'd be glad if someone could point out one or two tried and proven ones.

Thanks.

Comment: As interesting as this question is, I'd say it's totally off topic here and I'm voting to close as "Not Constructive" (read the definition and you'll probably agree). I think the Spring forums / mailing lists are the place to talk about this.

Comment: I don't see why this question is not constructive or off topic at all.

Answer (score 1):

The concept of a plugin can be achieved with the Spring bean factory. If you create a common interface you can define multiple beans that implement it and inject them where needed. Or you can use a factorybean to deliver the right plugin for the job.

Your idea of using events is called an 'Event Driven Architecture'. This goes a lot further than just plugins because it not only decouples from the implementation but also offers the possibility to decouple from which instance is used (multiple handlers), which location (multiple machines) and the time at which the request is handled (asynchronous handling). The tradeoff is an increased overall complexity, a reduced component-level complexity and the need for a messaging infrastructure. Often JMS is used, but if you just want a single-node setup both Spring and [Mule](http://www.mulesoft.com/) offer simple in-memory modes as well.

To help you further you should expand a bit on the requirements you are trying to meet and the architectural improvements you want. So far you have mentioned that you want to use plugins and described some possible solutions, but you have not really described what you are trying to achieve.